# Use Azure Pipline with UiPath to create and deploy nuget packages

Tags: azure-devops, uipath-orchestrator

**How to use azure pipleline for creating nugetpackes and deploying to orchestrator?**

The generation of the package is running with the following package: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uipath.vsts-uipath-package

In the case this is the right way what's the solution to upload them to orchestrator?

- Possibility 1: Create nuget feed in azure (one feed for TEST and one
  for PROD)
- Possibility 2: Deploy packages to orchestrator directly

Comment: Hi, is there good news for you to create a package then deploy to orchestrator by using UiPath? Feel free to leave comment there if you still facing any issue or puzzle:-)

Comment: Hi! Im not shure if this is the "correct" way. I think I will be better to create a nugetfeed where I have all my packes for the the orchestratro

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not one of the developer for UiPath, as I know, this extension hasn't integrated with our Azure Devops feed. So, your first possibility solution should not suitable in VSTS.

To achieve what you want, I suggest you pack and deploy the packages by using the **UiPath Package** task directly.

---

- **Create the package in build pipeline:**

Create a build pipeline, add and configure the UiPath Package task by following the description [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=uipath.vsts-uipath-package&ssr=false#overview). For create the package, please choose `Pack` as **Package action** value:

[image]

*Note:* Please keep the default value of **Output folder** as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`. It is the [path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) which used to store the artifact, then got by the release pipeline.

- **Deploy the package to orchestrator in Release pipeline:**

Create a Release pipeline, choose the build you executed previously as the source.

Add the same task into the stage, but here please choose `Deploy` as **Package action** value:

[image]

Then configure your Orchestrator info and the identity Authentication details.